# Program with select statements escape deadlock in go

Tags: go, select, deadlock, channel, goroutine

This question have quite possibly been answered by I couldn't find it so here we go:

I have this go function that sends or recieves "messages", whichever one is avaivable, using a select statement:

```
func Seek(name string, match chan string) {
select {
case peer := <-match:
    fmt.Printf("%s sent a message to %s.\n", peer, name)
case match <- name:
    // Wait for someone to receive my message.
```

I start this function on 4 different go-routines, using an unbuffered channel (It would be better to use a buffer och 1 but this is merely experimental):

```
people := []string{"Anna", "Bob", "Cody", "Dave"}
match := make(chan string)
for _, name := range people {
    go Seek(name, match, wg)
```

Now, I've just started using go and thought that since we're using an unbuffered channel, both the send and recieve statement of the "select" should block (there's no one waiting to send a message so you can't recieve, and there's no one waiting to recieve so you can't send), meaning that there won't be any communcation done between the functions, aka Deadlock. However running the code shows us that this is not the case:

```
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:48731
Dave sent a message to Cody.
Anna sent a message to Bob.
Process exiting with code: 0
```

My question to you lovely people is why this happens? Does the compiler realize that the functions want to read / write in the same channel and arranges that to happen? Or does the "select" statement continually check if there's anyone available to use the channel with?

Sorry if the question is hard to answer, I'm still a novice and not that experienced in how things operate behind the scene :)

Comment: I'm guessing the quote where it starts the goroutines is your `main()` - can you show the rest of it? I'm guessing your app just exits before anything can deadlock.

Comment: @Adrian Hi! I don't know the best way to post all of my code so I guess [this](https://gyazo.com/86377a87c8b29e2699caac868f9281f2) will do (it contains some changes that I don't belive are important to the issue). The thing is that I don't expect the program to print anything at all, I find it interesting that the program manages to deliver any messages at all.

Comment: I misread the code at first, it's not your `main`, it's your `select` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I've just started using go and thought that since we're using an unbuffered channel, both the send and recieve statement of the "select" should block (there's no one waiting to send a message so you can't recieve, and there's no one waiting to recieve so you can't send)

This is actually not true; in fact, there are multiple goroutines waiting to receive and multiple goroutines waiting to send. When a goroutine does a `select` like yours:

```
select {
case peer := <-match:
    fmt.Printf("%s sent a message to %s.\n", peer, name)
case match <- name:
    // Wait for someone to receive my message.
```

It is simultaneously waiting to send and to receive. Since you have multiple routines doing this, every routine will find both senders and receievers. Nothing will block. The `selects` will choose `case`s at random since multiple cases are unblocked at the same time.

Comment: Alright, that makes a lot of sense. I think the main issue is that I don't quite understand how the select-statement operates. Could you say that the two lines of code (sending and receiving) are running at the same time, and that the one that unblocks first is the one that's actually executed? (The analogy isn't great as it could entail the function sending messages to itself). Thank you so much!

Comment: That's one way to think of it. What actually happens [per the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) is that all of them are executed sequentially, in order, except for the channel operations. Then all of the channel operations are evaluated; if exactly one is unblocked, it is executed; if multiple are unblocked, one is chosen at random and executed; if all are blocked, it waits until one is unblocked.

Comment: One of Go's huge advantages (a side effect of its simplicity) is that the spec is short and readable. It's pretty dense so stuff like the Tour and Effective Go are the first reads but I'd definitely recommend reading the whole spec, it's not horribly long and is full of really useful information.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've looked at it before but I just now realized how readable and concise the documentation was. Great Recourse!